# Cleaning the DOM from anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($){
    //some code here...
});
</script>
```

This code will run after the page is loaded, but it will also run every time I call `$(window).trigger("load");`.

My questions are:

1. Where does that anonymous function lives?
2. Is it possible to remove it, and if "yes", how?

Regards!

EDIT: I'm not asking for an alternative methods, like switches, that will let me filter the execution of the anonymous function. I can't modify the code that inserts that function, so my only possible solution is to find out how to remove that function once it's loaded.

Comment: on window load you want to remove the function then why do you need that function?

Comment: No, I want to remove it at some random point in time, *after* the page has been loaded and *before* I *manually* trigger another 'load' event.

Comment: Why are you triggering `load` again? How can your page have loaded twice?

Comment: @TimRogers manually triggering another 'load' event is common when dealing with entire DOM replacement. (as in fetching the entire page again, via AJAX, and replacing the current one with `$("body".html(response);`).

Comment: @alexandernst Not common, and stupid approach. Use customs events.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question we have to look at [`jQuery.fn.init`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.init)

```
    // HANDLE: $(function)
    // Shortcut for document ready
} else if (jQuery.isFunction(selector)) {
    return rootjQuery.ready(selector);
}
```

Which calls [`jQuery.fn.ready`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.ready)

As you can see jQuery simply pushes the ready callback to a promise:

```
jQuery.ready.promise().done(fn);
```

From here there is no way to manipulate the actually stack.

*TLDR: Not posible to remove the function.*

---

#### Alternative Method:

Its not a good approach to trigger native events eg. `$(window).trigger('load');`.

What you can do instead is to trigger your own custom event:

```
$(window).trigger('page:load'); // Or something simulare.
```

And then make sure to trigger that event when the native event fires:

```
$(window).once('load', function() { // <- I'm using .once because load should only fire one time, and this way jQuery will unbind the listener for me 
    $(window).trigger('page:load');
});
```

Comment: @alexandernst I think what NULL is saying is 100% right. Found the same, after some research. You might want to use a custom-event, unless you are writing some quick-code. Anyway, let-us know why you are triggering this event.

Comment: As I already said in my edit (in the question), there is some JS code that I can't modify in any way. The only thing I can do is add more JS to do what I'm supposed to do, which is, request the entire content again, replace the entire body and then trigger the 'load' event so the newly loaded code can do it's job, but all that avoiding running the "old" JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a simple state variable, to determine weather to execute the anonymous function.

```
var is_window_inited = false;
$(function($){
    if( is_window_inited )
        return;
    is_window_inited = true;

    //some code here...
});
```

Comment: I can't modify the code that inserts the anonymous function.

Comment: @alexandernst Give me a few minutes. I'll think about it and update my answer. :)

Comment: @alexandernst I'm unable to find a way to unbind the onLoad handler, even after sufficient research. It's possible to do it on JQuery 1.4 and lower. But not on newer versions. Can you tell me why you are calling $(window).trigger("load") ? Lets see if we have alternatives to that.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a shortcut for binding a function to a `document` object `onready` event
2. <strike>You can look into `$(document).data('events')` for all your `$(function($))` bound events, and, as such, unbind them from there</strike>

2. Apparently `ready` isn't stored within the `data`, however looking into jquery source we can find what we're looking for in line #3119 (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js), where all `document.ready` (and other "special" events) are being inserted to Deferred object, and then fired based upon a number of conditions (and timeouts). As such, they are stored within Deferred object.

Ultimately, to answer your question, calling `$.Callbacks().empty()` should remove all `ready` functions from list of callbacks (at least from my understanding of the code; for some reason it doesn't, as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGMx7/ - idk, this is more question for jquery devs). However, as demonstrated in fiddle you can prevent the ready event from running by setting a simple flag.

Comment: Actually, I'm able to find what I'm looking for with `$(window).data('events');`. Bad thing is that I get 3 objects (functions) and I'm not sure how to delete only the one that I'm interested in. Let me try deleting everything and check if that fixes my problem.

Comment: Is it possible to find *all* events that jQuery has binded?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function($){
    //some code here...
   arguments.callee = null;
});
```

Comment: Not gonna work, and arguments.callee doesn't work in strict mode. Give your function a name instead if you need to reuse it. `function a() { console.log(a === arguments.callee) }`